# Add mutiple 2D array into 3D array in a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I encountered a problem in python programming.

I was manipulating the feature extraction in deep learning. I would like to add several 2D arrays into a 3D array in a for loop. I could achieve the purpose by using this easy way shown below. This method is not realistic in a large sample.

But in my situation, the data returned in the function of one sample is a 2D array (i.e. shape is (41,4)), the data itself is in the loop (i.e. 30 samples), the results I would like to obtain is a 3D array (i.e. shape is (30,41,4)).

I didn't find any related information, I really stuck here, hope someone could help me.

```
import numpy as np
 
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = np.array([[2,2,3],[4,5,6]])
c = np.array([[3,2,3],[4,5,6]])
print(a)
print(a.shape)
 
com = np.array([a,b,c])
print(com)
print(com.shape)
```

Comment: Just collect the samples in a list, and use `np.array` as you do.  List append is fine for this,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.stack](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack)

```
>>> arr = np.stack((a,b,c))
>>> arr
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[2, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[3, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
>>> arr.shape
(3, 2, 3)
```